# Detectar add-ons do Firefox com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-extensão

Criei uma extensão para o Chrome e Firefox, ambas estão em suas respectivas lojas Webstore e Addons Mozilla, objetivo é identificar se o usuário tem a extensão instalada caso contrario informar que é preciso instalar a extensão.

> Nota: no chrome eu consegui fazer, meu problema atual é identificar ela no Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi da seguinte maneira : 
No meu sistema faço uma verificação no localStorage para tentar encontrar um atributo o qual é setado pela extensão, caso encontre eu deduzo que a extensão está ali, e limpo o atributo no final da página

> OBS : A extensão sempre seta esse atributo ao entrar na determinada url

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de checar com JavaScript você pode injetar um script que crie uma variável global (no `window.`), assim por exemplo (esse exemplo é com WebExtension (suportado pelo Chrome, Firefox e Edge) o outro tipo de extensão esta descontinuado), então crie um `manifest.json` parecido com isto:

```
{
    "name": "Meu add-on",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Foo bar baz",
    "icons": {
        "128": "images/icon-128px.png",
        "48":  "images/icon-48px.png",
        "32":  "images/icon-32px.png",
        "16":  "images/icon.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [
            "*://dominio-que-ira-injectar-o-add-on.com/*"
        ],
        "js": [
            "checkaddon.js"
        ]
    }]
}
```

Na mesma pasta do `checkaddon.js` adicione isto:

```
window.MeuAddonAvailable = true;
```

Então no script do seu site faça a seguinte checagem:

```
if (!window.MeuAddonAvailable) {
     alert('Add-on não instalado');
}
```

Pode também mostrar um elemento que estava oculto:

```
function checkAddon()
{
    var notice = document.getElementById('notice-addon');

    if (window.MeuAddonAvailable) {
         notice.classList.remove("show");
    } else {
         notice.classList.add("show");
    }
}

if (/^(interactive|complete)$/i.test(document.readyState)) {
    checkAddon();
} else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', checkAddon);
}
```

O html seria algo como:

```html
<div id="notice-addon">
Instale o add-on
</div>
```

E o CSS assim:

```css
#notice-addon {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     display: none;
     background-color: #f44336;
     color: #fff;
}

#notice-addon {
     display: block;
}
```

Comment: Bem melhor dessa forma